# Hash with Chaining Problems

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, computer-science, hash-function

I ran into an example in Computer Science Course.

suppose we use Hashing with chanining and use table of size `m`. the hash function map record with key `k` into `k mod m` slot. if we know the record keys is subset of {$i^2 | 1 \leq i \leq 100 $}, for which  value of  `m` cost of search is lower in worst case?

a) 11

b) 7

c) 9

d) 12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We consider four different hashtables with sizes $m=7,9,11$ and $m=12$ and start with
>
> **the case $m=7$:**
>
> We consider the multiset
>
> \begin{align*}
> \{i^2 \mod m \left|1\leq i \leq 100\right.\}
> \end{align*}
>   and count the multiplicities of occurrences of the hash keys $\{0,\ldots,m-1\}$. The multiplicities give the chain length per hash key of the hash table. This number minus one is the number of collisions per hash key.
>
> \begin{array}{lccccccc}
> \text{key}&0&1&2&3&4&5&6\\
> \text{nr. occ}&14&\color{red}{\mathbf{29}}&28&0&\color{red}{\mathbf{29}}&0&0\\
> \end{array}

**We observe:** Using $m=7$ we have in the worst case a chain of length $29$, which means $28$ collisions.

> Let's have a look at the table of all sizes of $m$ with the hash key and the number of occurrences, i.e. the chain length.
>
> \begin{array}{rlrrrrrrrrrrrr}
> m&\text{hash}&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11\\
> \hline
> 7&\text{nr. occ}&14&\color{red}{\mathbf{29}}&28&0&\color{red}{\mathbf{29}}&0&0\\
> 9&\text{nr. occ}&\color{red}{\mathbf{33}}&23&0&0&22&0&0&22&0\\
> 11&\text{nr. occ}&9&\color{blue}{\mathbf{19}}&0&18&18&18&0&0&0&18&0\\
> 12&\text{nr. occ}&16&33&0&0&\color{red}{\mathbf{34}}&0&0&0&0&17&0&0\\
> \end{array}

We tabulate the cost of search in the worst case for the different $m$ values

\begin{array}{rc}
m&max\\
\hline
7&29\\
9&33\\
11&\color{blue}{\mathbf{19}}\\
12&34\\
\end{array}

> We conclude the **lowest cost** in the worst case is $m=11$ with a chain length of $19$.

Comment: @nini: Hi, Nini! Thanks a lot for accepting my answer and granting the bounty! :-) Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what the assumptions on $m$ are -- clearly if $m>100^2$, then any search is going to be cost 1, so probably the values up to $100^2$ are to be studied or better yet, only a minimal one is to be found.

In the latter case, the respective answers are 19, 29, 23 and 17.

In the former case, say, with 11, you can show that $m=128$ doesn't work since you have the 13 squares of everything which is $4\bmod(8)$, `4 12 20 28 36 44 52 60 68 76 84 92 100`, mapping to $16$. But everything past $128$ works, i.e. you don't need to go up to $m=10^4$.

Similar arguments/remarks work for the rest. The question is, however, what the CS course was about. If its asking about worst-case (as as opposed to average-case) cost of explicit numbers for hash tables, I'd assume something below the level of [CLRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) (few intro courses aren't...) If that is correct, I'd assume that nobody wanted you to use case-by-case + big guns elementary number theory analysis -- rather they wanted you to write 15 lines of C++ or 10 lines of Python and find out.

Comment: the answer is 11. i couldn't understand who we get this !